# Zaki Like Dislike Comments plugin cause headers already send error

Tags: wordpress

When using wordpress Zaki Like `Dislike Comments plugin` on `php 5.3` server, I received

> Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output
>   started at
>   /home/otzyvdom/domatop.ru/docs/wp-content/plugins/zaki-like-dislike-comments/classes/class-zaki-like-dislike.php:169)

Answer (score 0):

That is why Zaki Like Dislike Comments uses `add_action('comment_text','ZakiLikeDislike_AddPluginHml');` hook to add like/dislike buttons in comment text. But the comment_text event occures not only when post with comments is shown but during comment form proceeding etc. And ZakiLikeDislike_AddPluginHml function makes echo instead of modifying comment content!

Finally to avoid this error you must modify main function like this:
    function ZakiLikeDislike_AddPluginHml($content) {
        $settings = get_option('zaki_like_dislike_options');
        ob_start();
        if($settings['show']) : 
            echo ZakiLikeDislike::getLikeDislikeHtml();
        endif;
        $out = ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();
        return $out.$content;
    }